# What components might have blown due to reverse when battery was connected backwards?

Tags: amplifier, automotive

I have offered to take a look at my friend's amp after they accidentally wired it up backwards. Expecting to find some physical damage or any number of damaged components, I opened it up (after checking all the fuses with a multimeter). Nothing visible at all, so I hooked it up to a bench supply. Protection light flashes, and then nothing. The voltage across what should be 13.8VDC had dropped to ~7VDC, but no smells, heat, noises...

It's a 4*100WRMS (at 4 Ohm) amp that had no faults or funny business before very briefly being connected in reverse. I'm hoping an amp circuit guru will be able to see the likely components to check, as without a hint (visual or otherwise) I'd just be poking around in the dark.

Thanks for any tips in advance!

[image][image]

Comment: "The voltage across what should be 13.8VDC had dropped to ~7VDC" what does this mean? Without a schematics it would be very difficult to estimate all circuits that are damaged.

Comment: A note to engineers - always assume the users are idiots and plan accordingly with blocking diodes

Comment: @DirkBruere as an engineer, I can assure you fellow engineers are nearly as stupid as I am, so I design with blocking diodes if I design for engineers.

Comment: If your power supply voltage dropped to 7VDC that means the current limit was activated. That means the amp is trying to use more current than the limit set on the power supply. That means either the amp has a short circuit somewhere (and **is** damaged) or you simply set the current limit too low (sometimes this is easy to do by accident, so check it)

Comment: There is a sort of push-pull converter at the input side to step up the voltage. Assuming they are MOSFETs they all have melted due to intrinsic diode.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič
Sorry, I could have been clearer. I mean that the power supply is fixed 13.8VDC and remains around that with a working amplifier in a steady state. When this damaged amp is connected the voltage across +/- drops to ~7VDC. The supply is fixed limit of 20A, which the amp shouldn't be close to without load.

Comment: @Dirk
Right?? Especially in the car audio world, where everyone thinks they are sound engineers and auto elecs.

Marko again, they are MOSFETS, SFP50N06 - are you suggesting testing these first? I would have thought something closer to the power supply would have failed first (likely my lack of understanding though).

And as I type I have just seen the answers posted. Thank you everyone, I will follow up there :)

Comment: 7V@20A -> R=0.35ohm, P=140W. So if you remove bolts and lift  those 12 transistors , it will be hot like hell. You should switch the PSU on for 2s, then off and touch which one is hot. It is not plausible that any component that isn't bolted on heatsink would remain without any signs of destruction.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, right to left, the DC 12V input appears to be connected to:

- a bunch of caps on the right, these got reverse biased but should survive
- then most likely a push pull DC-DC to make a high frequency square wave, these are the 6 pairs of TO220 MOSFETs on the right side of the photos ; these got reverse biased so they acted as diodes, what happened next depends on who died first, the fuse in the power line or the MOSFETs
- Then that square wave goes through the two toroid transformers, then the two pairs of rectifying diodes (labeled Dxxxx, on the heat sink) then the large higher voltage caps.
- The rest is a standard Class-AB amp.

With the 12V in reverse, the switching power supply would not operate. The amp on the left side of the picture wouldn't need any 12V to operate, so it wouldn't be connected to it, so it shouldn't even have noticed the incident.

Most of the MOSFETs from the push pull converter are most likely melted short or blown open. They are shorting your power supply, which goes into current limit, hence the drop in voltage. Shorted FETs would be a much better outcome, because that would limit the damage and blow the fuse faster.

Extra circuits that would use 12V as power supply, like maybe a microcontroller, or whatever was connected to that ribbon cable in the middle, also got -12V so their fate would depend on design.

The driver for that switching converter, which is most likely the 16 pin DIP in the center and its 8 pin DIP along with the 4 transistors, would definitely be powered from 12V, so it is suspicious. The gate protection zeners could have blown too.

So basically, this board has two sides, the class-AB amp on the left is most likely fine, you could probably still use it with a +/-30V power supply. That's from the left edge up to the rightmost big green resistor.

And all semiconductors on the right part of the board should be checked. Expect lots of casualties.

You can check continuity between the 12V input and the ribbon cable to see if whatever is on the other end got -12V. If that is the case, expect damage on this board too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is similar to yours PSU at the input. It's a push-pull converter. There are two for each channel. When you inverted the supply, all transistor in-built diodes conducted thus blowing the fuse. But it seems that at least one is damaged.

So you should unmount all of them from the heatsink, just those close to the input and marked with Q. Those marked with D are the diodes at the output from transformer, nothing is blown after the transformer.

You do apply some voltage with your lab PSU and use your fingers to detect which heats up.